# execution of individual test suite using pybot command where a folder has _init.txt file

Tags: python, robotframework

Need the command to execute the individual test suite using pybot for robot framework.
1. we had an initialization file(_init.txt) where all the prerequisites are scripted.
2. few test suite files which covers so many test scenarios.

How to execute individual  test suite which uses _init.txt file and then run the specific test suite.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell pybot to run the test suite that contains the init, then use command line options to choose the tests or suites you want to run. For example, you can pick tests by test name, suite name, or by tag.

The robot framework user guide has a section on picking test cases to run, appropriately named [Selecting test cases](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#selecting-test-cases).

For example, consider a structure like this:

```
tests
   + product_a
     +- __init__.txt
     +- feature_a.txt
```

To run all of the tests in `feature_a.txt` and also reap the benefits of the code in `__init__.txt`, you would run it like this:

```
$ pybot --suite feature_a tests/product_a
```

(note: you could also specify `tests` rather than `tests/product_a`)

Likewise, if `feature_a.txt` has a test case named "test1" and you want to run only that test, you would do something like this:

```
$ pybot --suite feature_a --test test1 tests/product_a
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am looking for the command to execute the testsuite from a test directory which has _init_.txt common to all files.

Comment: @Manojpalle: I don't understand your comment. That's exactly what I described: how to run a test or sub-suite that is inside a suite with an init.txt.